# Zooming using slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a beginner with jQuery and looking to build a short plugin for my requirement. I am looking to build a light and short timeline like plugin which has to look something like the following:

[image]

The green bar below has two small rectangles which can be moved left and right towards or away from each other to zoom in / zoom out the content of the timeline above (orange bar). I tried to find similar plugin which I could use as a reference to write to zoom in/zoom out using the slider.
I found some timeline plugins such as Timeglider etc. which have the zoom functionality  implemented in a different way and not similar to the above figure (where I could use two rectangles to zoom in/zoom out and zoom timeline in orange bar).

I wanted to ask for suggestions about where I could find a similar plugin that I could use as a reference to see how zooming using slider is implemented. Or if there's no such already plugin, I would appreciate some help on how to go about the zooming functionaility for the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know, that there is the slider plugin for jQuery UI ([link](http://jqueryui.com/slider/)). It will be just question of styling it, connecting to slide event and changing zoom level on the go.

I would expand my answer, but I lack some more information about your HTML layout, Would like to see some code of yours in jsfiddle.net.

Comment: I'll make a fiddle and post comment here after some time